# Drawing Text with animation and Lines on existing Video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I Want to add text with animation and lines on existing video in android. Can some one suggest me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, however I can point you to a direction for video rendering in android. See [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android)